# How can I update table column values from YYYYMMDD to YYYYMM

Tags: sql, sql-server

| Account_Open_Date |
| --- |
| 19931122 |
| 20041102 |

So I want to convert the dates to be

| Account_Open_Date |
| --- |
| 199311 |
| 200411 |

```
SELECT 
    CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), a.Account_Open_Date, 112) AS int)
FROM 
    [tempdb].[dbo].[SQL Test Data] a
WHERE 
    Account_Open_Date is NOT NULL;
```

This select statement pulls up the dates how I want them but I want to update the table to the same format and am having a hard time with Updating. I don't have a good example of what I have tried.

```
UPDATE x.Account_Open_Date
SET a.Account_Open_Date = CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), Account_Open_Date, 112) AS int)
FROM 
    ([tempdb].[dbo].[SQL Test Data]) x
WHERE 
    Account_Open_Date is NOT NULL;
```

Comment: could you please clarify what datatype has the column Account_Open_Date

Comment: `199311` That is NOT a date - think carefully BEFORE you do this and consider how this column is currently used and what plans you have for future use.

Comment: Why are not not using an actual date and time data type to store dates?

Comment: You should store dates in a date column, not `varchar` or `int`. You can use `EOMONTH` to get a single date per month

Comment: If you want the first 6 digits, why not just use substring (for strings) or division by 100 (for integers)? It's not a date anyway, now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments bring up excellent points. Seeing as you are doing this on a temp table I will assume you are testing and wont dive into the points brought up.

Fixed your update statement. You were close.

```
update x 
SET 
    x.Account_Open_Date = CAST(convert(varchar(6),Account_Open_Date,112) as int) 
FROM 
    [tempdb].[dbo].[SQL Test Data] x 
WHERE 
   Account_Open_Date is NOT NULL;
```

Comment: You the man! Thanks!